# Prediction interval for ACP model in R

Tags: r, time-series, confidence-interval, poisson, autoregressive-models

I'm trying to teach myself a bit about modeling time series for 'counts' data. I found a pretty simple model, the Autoregressive Conditional Poisson model (ACP) (Heinen 2003), that has an accompanying R package {acp}. I'm having trouble finding information about how to construct n-step-ahead prediction intervals for predictions made from an ACP model. Inconveniently, forecast doesn't work with these ACP objects. Any thoughts on how to construct these?

Additionally, when using predict() with an ACP model, you have to include an argument, newydata, that is a data frame of the values you want to predict...? Maybe I'm misinterpreting this, but it seems like you need to already have y when predicting yhat. Why?

Below I copy/pasted the example code from the {acp} package.

```
library(acp)

data(polio)
trend=(1:168/168)
cos12=cos((2*pi*(1:168))/12)
sin12=sin((2*pi*(1:168))/12)
cos6=cos((2*pi*(1:168))/6)
sin6=sin((2*pi*(1:168))/6)

#Autoregressive Conditional Poisson Model with explaning covariates
polio_data<-data.frame(polio, trend , cos12, sin12, cos6, sin6)
mod1 <- acp(polio~-1+trend+cos12+sin12+cos6+sin6,data=polio_data, p = 1 ,q = 2)
summary(mod1)

#Static out-of-sample fit example
train<-data.frame(polio_data[c(1: 119),])
mod1t <- acp(polio~-1+trend+cos12+sin12+cos6+sin6,data=train, p = 1 ,q = 2)
xpolio_data<-data.frame(trend , cos12, sin12, cos6, sin6)
test<-xpolio_data[c(120:nrow(xpolio_data)),]
yfor<-polio_data[120:nrow(polio_data),1]
predict(mod1t,yfor,test)

#Autoregressive Conditional Poisson Model without explaning covariates
polio_data<-data.frame(polio)
mod2 <- acp(polio~-1,data=polio_data, p = 3 ,q = 1)
summary(mod2)
```

The second argument in the predict() command is the vector of observed y values that confuses me.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include an example like some code?

Comment: For sure- edited.